# InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer (JWT Authentication configuration .Net Core 2.2)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

I'm trying to implement JWT Authentication in my Web API Project (developed in .Net Core 2.2), But I'm getting an error due to the configuration in Startup Class. When I run my Application without this code then it runs perfectly without any error. here is the configuration code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Issuer").Value,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Issuer").Value,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Key").Value))

                };
            });
```

and this is the error
[image]

Please any solution?

Comment: remove options inside `AddAuthentication` and leave it empty `services.AddAuthentication()`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify as per below.

```
   services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Issuer").Value,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Issuer").Value,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").GetSection("Key").Value))

                };
            });
```